# Logback - Passing variables/values to logger method and pattern

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

`Spring Boot 2.3.1` web application, using a logger (default `Logback`), configuration like in https://www.baeldung.com/logback

A pattern is defined in an appender, for example:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

In code, when I call i.e. `LOGGER.info("My message")`, the value `"My message"` ist mapped to `%msg` in the pattern. The other placeholders in the pattern, like `%thread`, `%level`, etc. are getting the values automatically.

In a REST controller, within a request method, I would also like to log some values from `HttpServletRequest`, like remote address, etc.

Can I pass the `HttpServletRequest` values (like `request.getMethod()`, `request.getPathInfo()`) so that it is mapped to some placeholders in the pattern? Like `%ip (remote address)`, `%method (method like GET, POST, etc.)`, or `%path (path info)`, etc.

Like defining the pattern:

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %method %pathinfo %ip %msg %n</pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the values you want to MDC context and reference them in your log  pattern